# Sqlalchemy Can't put the bindkey in base model class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to add a __bind_key__ attribute to my base model class which should be inherited by all my DB models. However this throws an error :

```
AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute '__table__'
```

My base model class looks like this:

```
class Base(db.Model):
    """Convenience base DB model class."""
    __abstract__ = True

    __bind_key__ = 'abc_db'
```

The basic idea is to connect to multiple databases and bind the respective models to the tables.

Comment: That's because I want to connect to multiple databases which are not on the same server. I figured out that the best way of doing this is using the SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. And there a lot of models which should include this   \__bind_key\__ attribute. More details [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/binds/)

Comment: Yeah, familiar with that feature, but "and there a lot [sic] of models which should include this `__bind_key__`" sounds like a perfect use case for making that the default bind, and the ones that need to use other binds then define what ever bind they need. Unless you'll not be basing all of your models on `Base`, which of course would invalidate what I just said.

Comment: Let us suppose the case that I have to connect to two different databases (of course on different servers) and say we have 50 models in each DB. In that case having a base model with this attribute which gets inherited would be ideal. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable and something that'd help understanding the question's context, if included in the question itself. That also means that the link I provided before does not help you, unfortunately. Removed some of the earlier comments that were made obsolete by the additional info.